# Difference between "level" and "degree"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences, synonyms, british-english

Can we change the word "degree" for "level" in this sentence:

> *They developed a high degree of self-criticism.*

If it is possible, what would be the difference in meaning?

Comment: To my ear they are a little different. _High degree_ to me suggests that they do a lot of self-criticism, whereas _high level_ suggests to me that they are good at self-criticism.

Comment: There is almost no difference in general usage but if you want to be specific, *degrees* are precise and *levels* represent groups or stages.

Very loosely, you might compare *degrees* to the individual steps on a staircase, and *levels* to the floors in the building.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find that degree is a word used in measurement and as such implies more precision in the phrase. Using "level" would be more useful in comparing two amounts. One is of a higher level than the other.

The actual difference is minimal and might only be noticed by a native English speaker.